# azure generateAccountSAS vs generateBlobSAS

Tags: node.js, azure, devops

I have an azure storage account with several containers and blobs:

```
container1 -> blob1.txt, blob2.jpg
container2 -> blob1.png
container3 ->
```

I want to generate a SAS that can only read and write from **container1**.

First question: Should i be using generateAccountSASQueryParameters or generateBlobSASQueryParameters to do this?

Second question: I have been trying to get this working with generateBlobSASQueryParameters. However, i keep getting this error:

```
<Error>
  <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
  <Message>
    Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is 
    formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:1db4c573-201e-0083-2396-ab3df5000000 
  Time:2019-12-05T18:05:52.8934222Z
  </Message>
  <AuthenticationErrorDetail>
    The specified signed resource is not allowed for the this resource level
  </AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

The code that I'm using to do this is here:

```
const account = "storageaccountname";
const accountKey = "<myKey>";
const sharedKeyCredential = new AzureStorageBlob.StorageSharedKeyCredential(account, accountKey);
const blobServiceClient = new AzureStorageBlob.BlobServiceClient(
  `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net`,
  sharedKeyCredential
);

const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient('container1')

const sas = AzureStorageBlob.generateBlobSASQueryParameters({
  containerName: 'container1',
  protocol: AzureStorageBlob.SASProtocol.HTTPS,
  permissions: 'rw',
  resourceTypes: 'sco',
  startsOn: new Date(),
  expiresOn: new Date(new Date().valueOf() + 86400),
}, sharedKeyCredential)
res.status(200).json(`https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net/?${sas.toString()}`)
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to my test, if you want to create a SAS token to create and read blob in one container, please refer to the following code

1. install package

```
npm install @azure/storage-blob
```

2. Code

```
var storage = require("@azure/storage-blob")

async function generateSasToken1() {

const accountname ="blobstorage0516";
    const key = "";
    const cerds = new storage.StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountname,key);
    var startDate = new Date();
    var expiryDate = new Date();
    startDate.setTime(startDate.getTime() - 5*60*1000);
    expiryDate.setTime(expiryDate.getTime() + 24*60*60*1000);
const containerName="test";
    // if the container does not exit, please run the following code to create
    // const blobServiceClient = new storage.BlobServiceClient(
    //   `https://${accountname}.blob.core.windows.net`,
    //   sharedKeyCredential
    // );
    // const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName)
    // await  containerClient.create()
    const containerSAS = storage.generateBlobSASQueryParameters({
      expiresOn : expiryDate,
      permissions: storage.ContainerSASPermissions.parse("rwl"),
      protocol: storage.SASProtocol.Https,
      containerName: containerName,
      startsOn: startDate,
      version:"2018-03-28"

    },cerds).toString();

    console.log(containerSAS);
    const containerUrl="https://"+accountname+".blob.core.windows.net/"+containerName+"?"+containerSAS
    const client =new storage.ContainerClient(containerUrl);

    for (let index = 0; index < 7; index++) {
      // Create a blob(write)
      const content = "hello";
      const blobName = "newblob" + new Date().getTime();
      const blobClient = client.getBlobClient(blobName);
      const blockBlobClient = blobClient.getBlockBlobClient();
      const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.upload(content, content.length);
      console.log(`Uploaded block blob ${blobName} successfully`, uploadBlobResponse.requestId);
    }

    //  List blobs(list)
    let i = 1;
    let iter = await client.listBlobsFlat();
    for await (const blob of iter) {
      console.log(`Blob ${i++}: ${blob.name}`);
    }

    // download blob(read)
    const blobClient = client.getBlobClient("test.json");
    const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blobClient.download(0);
    console.log(
      "Downloaded blob content",
      await streamToString(downloadBlockBlobResponse.readableStreamBody)
    );
}
async function streamToString(readableStream) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const chunks = [];
    readableStream.on("data", (data) => {
      chunks.push(data.toString());
    });
    readableStream.on("end", () => {
      resolve(chunks.join(""));
    });
    readableStream.on("error", reject);
  });
}

generateSasToken1()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Successfully executed sample.");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
  });
```

[image]

For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas)

Comment: Thanks. I was missing the /${containerName}/${blobName} in the URL